# How to get ID using class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get ID using class in jQuery? I am able to get text, but I need ID? Using this
I am able to get text:

```
 `var selectedItem=$('.jstree-clicked').text();`
```

when I used this

```
var selectedItem=$('.jstree-clicked').id;
```

it gives undefined. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/160/

Comment: because `$('.jstree-clicked')` returns a jQuery object, not a dom element reference

Comment: Please check the fiddle and follow the steps http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/161/Please follow this steps .Expand "b" click "b-a" and then click button .It should give ID

Comment: i think the `jstree-clicked` not getting added on the click. I have debugged your fiddle , that selector gives nothing even i have clicked a node.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
  $('.jstree-clicked').parent()[0].id;
```

using jquery:

```
  $('.jstree-clicked').parent().attr('id');
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fuu94/167/)**

Comment: `.prop()` would be a better choice than `.attr()`

Comment: @milin correct answer ..can you solve my second problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732061/why-is-parent-is-giving-false-value-at-all-time

Comment: Hi Naveen, Actually there is no such class 'jstree-clicked' because, when i checked for $('.jstree-clicked').length, it returns 0 which means there is no such class.

Comment: @asprin: From what I understand in the difference between attr and prop, it's only relevant when setting values, less so when getting them. I could be wrong though :)